# Generate Graphene Mutation Inputs from SQLAlchemy Class Attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I currently have the following mutation defined for my project:

My class `PlanetAttribute`  is used to define Graphene Fields used as inputs of my mutations

```
class PlanetAttribute:
    name = graphene.String(required=True, description="Name of the planet.")
    rotation_period = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Rotation period of the planet.")
    orbital_period = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Orbital period of the planet.")
    diameter = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Diameter of the planet.")
    climate = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Climate period of the planet.")
    gravity = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Gravity of the planet.")
    terrain = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Terrain of the planet.")
    surface_water = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Surface water of the planet.")
    population = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="Population of the planet.")
    url = graphene.String(default_value="unknown", description="URL of the planet in the Star Wars API.")
```

My class `CreatePlanetInput` is used to define the Graphene input object type. Note that it inherits its attributes from the `PlanetAttribute` class defined above.

```
class CreatePlanetInput(graphene.InputObjectType, PlanetAttribute):
    """Arguments to create a planet."""
    pass
```

My class `CreatePlanet` is my Graphene mutation class which takes the `CreatePlanetInput` class as arguments.

```
class CreatePlanet(graphene.Mutation):
    """Create a planet."""
    planet = graphene.Field(lambda: Planet, description="Planet created by this mutation.")

    class Arguments:
        input = CreatePlanetInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = utils.input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['created'] = datetime.utcnow()
        data['edited'] = datetime.utcnow()

        planet = ModelPlanet(**data)
        db_session.add(planet)
        db_session.commit()

        return CreatePlanet(planet=planet)
```

Instead of declaring mutation inputs manually in the `PlanetAttribute` class, I would rather generate them dynamically from my SQLALchemy class `ModelPlanet` which is defined as below:

```
class ModelPlanet(Base):
    """Planet model."""

    __tablename__ = 'planet'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, doc="Id of the person.")
    name = Column('name', String, doc="Name of the planet.")
    rotation_period = Column('rotation_period', String, doc="Rotation period of the planet.")
    orbital_period = Column('orbital_period', String, doc="Orbital period of the planet.")
    diameter = Column('diameter', String, doc="Diameter of the planet.")
    climate = Column('climate', String, doc="Climate period of the planet.")
    gravity = Column('gravity', String, doc="Gravity of the planet.")
    terrain = Column('terrain', String, doc="Terrain of the planet.")
    surface_water = Column('surface_water', String, doc="Surface water of the planet.")
    population = Column('population', String, doc="Population of the planet.")
    created = Column('created', String, doc="Record created date.")
    edited = Column('edited', String, doc="Record last updated date.")
    url = Column('url', String, doc="URL of the planet in the Star Wars API.")

    peopleList = relationship(ModelPeople, backref='planet')
```

How would you proceed?

Note that I have also posted the question here: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/112

Comment: See also [this discussion](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/285).

Answer (score 5):

I solved creating this class:

```
from graphene.types.utils import yank_fields_from_attrs
from graphene.utils.subclass_with_meta import SubclassWithMeta_Meta
from graphene_sqlalchemy.registry import get_global_registry
from graphene_sqlalchemy.types import construct_fields

class SQLAlchemyInputObjectType(graphene.InputObjectType):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass_with_meta__(  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
        cls, model=None, registry=None, only_fields=(), exclude_fields=(),
        optional_fields=(), **options
    ):
        if not registry:
            registry = get_global_registry()

        sqla_fields = yank_fields_from_attrs(
            construct_fields(model, registry, only_fields, exclude_fields),
            _as=graphene.Field,
        )

        for key, value in sqla_fields.items():
            if key in optional_fields:
                type_ = value.type if isinstance(
                    value.type, SubclassWithMeta_Meta) else value.type.of_type
                value = type_(
                    description=value.description
                )
            setattr(cls, key, value)

        super(SQLAlchemyInputObjectType, cls).__init_subclass_with_meta__(
            **options
        )
```

You can use it with:

```
class CreatePlanetInput(SQLAlchemyInputObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelPlanet
        exclude_fields = ('id', )
```

I tried to make it behave similar with `SQLAlchemyObjectType`, so `only_fields` and `exclude_fields` should work as expected.

I also added an `optional_fields` that makes it not required, good for an update mutation.

It does handle the simple cases, like scalar fields. Relationships, like `peopleList`, you need have to declare manually.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: I have an error which says the following names are undefined: `get_global_registry`, `yank_fields_from_attrs`, `construct_fields`, `SubclassWithMeta_Meta` where do you import them from?

Comment: Added them in the answer.